# Changing a column's datatype before disabling foreign key constraint and index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints, indexing

I want to change a column's data type.

Because the column is referenced as a foreign key with 2 other tables, I need to drop the foreign key constraint on the other 2 tables.

Also the current table has index which needs to be dropped.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the index and foreign key names, which can be pulled from the `sys` tables.  The syntax to drop them is:

**Foreign Key**

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[foreign_key_index_name]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tablename]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tablename] DROP CONSTRAINT [foreign_key_index_name]
```

**Index**

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tablename]') AND name = N'index_name')
DROP INDEX [index_name] ON [dbo].[tablename] WITH ( ONLINE = OFF )
```

This information is also available in BOL.

You can find the index and foreign key names with these queries:

```
select * from sys.indexes where object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[tablename]')
select * from sys.foreign_keys where parent_object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[tablename]')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I change the column data type without actually dropping the index and constraint. Can I disable them instead?

Comment: As far as I know, you must recreate a table to change the datatype of a column.  This means you have to drop and recreate the table, its indexes and foreign keys.  If you change the column type using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), it will script the entire operation for you.  The one issue I've seen though is when you change a column to be 'not null' after the table has data in it, the script will fail unless you bind a default to the column, or edit the script to set the field to a non-null value when the script transfers the data from the temp table into the newly created table.